# Look at the time series plot, how to tell if the data is "random" and nonnormal or not?

Tags: time-series, self-study, random-variable

I tried to solve this exercise in the book of "Time Series Analysis with Application in R":

> Simulate a completely random process of length 48 with independent,
>   chi-square distributed values, each with 2 degrees of freedom. Display
>   the time series plot. Does it look “random” and nonnormal? Repeat this
>   exercise several times with a new simulation each time.

I run this command five times and get five plots:

```
plot(rchisq(48, 2), type='o')
```

[image: Five plots of <code>rchisq</code> as time series]

Look at the above plots, how do I say if they look "random" and nonnormal or not? How can I know that a variable is "nonnormal" or "random" by looking at the time series plots?

Thank you so much.

Comment: The point of this question is extremely personal: the only possible objective answer lies in the fact that you *created* these data randomly.  By inspecting them and reflecting on them *yourself,* you will learn what independent (but non-normal) series of data look like.

Comment: Thank you @Tavrock for pointing out the `[self-study]` tag, I added it to the question.

Comment: Thank @whuber, in this case, I see that those results look "random". However, I don't know what is a "normal" series of data and what it looks like. Could you tell me an example of "normal" series of data please?

Comment: @HieuLe, try plotting `plot(rnorm(48, 2), type='o')` a few times and comparing the plots between the two distributions.  You may even want to try `plot(rchisq(48, 2), type='o'); lines(rnorm(48, 2), type='o', col ="blue")` to overlay a random normal plot on top of the $\chi^2$ plot.

Comment: Thanks @Tavrock, I drew these plots and see the differences.